Ross' Model - Classification of equilibrium point $(0,0)$ given that $pqa^2d=\alpha\mu$
Considering
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dot{m}=pa(1-m)h-\mu m \\
\dot{h}=qad(1-h)m-\alpha h
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $m$ is the proportion of infected mosquitoes and $h$ is the proportion of infected humans and $d$ represents the density of mosquitoes per human ($d=\frac{M}{H}).$
I'm interested in analysing if $(0,0)$ is a unstable equilibria given that $pqa^2d=\alpha\mu$, whereas this condition gives us that the stability theorem is inconclusive $(|J(F)_{(0,0)}|=0;tr(J(F)_{(0,0)})<0)$. I also know that there is no other equilibrium point as  $pqa^2d \leq \alpha \mu$.
As $Q=[0,1]^2$ is simply connected, by Bendixson's Criterion $(tr(J(F)_{(0,0)})<0)$, there is no closed orbit that is totally contained in $Q$; so by Poincaré-Bendixson's Theorem, if we get rid of an homoclynic orbit, then we could say that $(0,0)$ is assymptotically stable. But looking at the initial monotonicity of the solutions beginning at $\partial Q$

Any suggestions?
